# Converting the first element in a list of strings to an integer

Tags: haskell

the list is:

```
l = ["1","kg","g"]
```

I found this method but it didn't work:

```
    map (convert) l
    convert [x, "kg", "g"] = (read x :: Integer) *1000
```

I got the following error:

```
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
17 |     convert [x, "kg", "g"] = (read x :: Integer) *1000
   |                            ^                ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not convert values with a typehint. Haskell has a *strong* type system, which means that you can only use functions to turn a `String` in an `Integer` for example.

Since `Integer` is an instance of the [**`Read`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Read), you can use [**`read :: Read a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) to parse a string to an `Integer`:

```
convert [x, "kg", "g"] = (read x :: Integer) *1000
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I just finished understanding the Read type class.
Unfortunately, in gives me the same error still.

Comment: @AnasHesham: but you use `map convert l`, that makes no sense, since `l` is a list of strings, you thus call `convert l` to ogtain the result.

Comment: @AnasHesham: you also do not need to define a signature for `read`. `read` is available from the `Prelude`.

Comment: @AnasHesham: furthermore as said, you can not use `map` since it makes no sense: `convert` expects a list of strings, not single string, since `l` is a list of strings, mapping makes no sense, you call it with `r = convert l` (and then `r` is thus an `Integer`

Comment: I put map as I intend to use the convert on a list of lists that contain the same type of data that is available in the example. But yes its currently redundant in the current iteration of the code.